# How to parse "I had made arrangement for my affairs to be dealt with by one of my children"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I had made arrangements for my affairs to be dealt with by one of my
>   children.

I have different understandings of this sentence.

> (1) I /had made/ arrangements/ for ( my affairs/ to be dealt with/ by
>   one of my children ).  In my opinion, the phrase which is between
>   parentheses is the reduction of a subordinate clause,namely "My
>   affairs can be dealt with by one of my children".  So the whole
>   sentence means that : I had made arrangement in order to let it
>   happen.
>
> (2) I/ had made /arrangements /for my affairs/ to be dealt with /by one
>   of my children. = I had made arrangement for my affairs which can be
>   dealt with by one of my children.
>
> (3) I /had made/ arrangements [for my affairs to be dealt with by one
>   of my children].  for my affairs to be dealt with by one of my
>   children is a complement of arrangement.

I don't know how to parse this sentence?

Comment: Where did you get this? Are you sure it's typed correctly?(I would use the plural _arrangements_.)

Comment: @J.R. yes, you are right. I have corrected them.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix clause employs the idiom *MAKE arrangements for X*, meaning approximately “perform whatever actions are necessary are necessary to ensure that X happens”.

Like many *VERB for* ‘prospective’ idioms—*look for*, *prepare for*, *provide for*, etc.—this idiom takes as its complement either an ordinary NP or a full clause employing an infinitive marked with the particle *to*. If the subject of the complement clause is  present, it is cast in the objective case, as if were the object of the preposition

> We made arrangements for [a birthday party].
>   We made arrangements for [him to attend the party].

If the complement clause has the same subject as the head clause, both the subject and *for* are omitted:

> We made arrangements <sup><s>for</s> [<s>us</s></sup> to attend the party].

In the case of your example, the complement clause has the ‘canonical’ form

> My affairs *BE* dealt with by one of my children.

If this were an independent clause, *BE* would be a finite verb construction. Since the object of arrangements is inherently prospective, this construction would ordinarily take a futurive auxiliary of some sort, and since the arrangements in question took place in the past the construction would be cast in the past form.

> My affairs would<sup>Past Futurive</sup> be dealt with by one of my children.

So the sentence can be paraphrased:

> I had taken the steps necessary to ensure that my affairs would be dealt with by one of my children.

Comment: Nice answer. So you analyze this sentence as following: I had made arrangement for [my affairs to be dealt with by one of my children]. You deem "my affairs to be dealt with by one of my children" as a whole. But what about "I have a chair for you to sit on"? Can you regard "you to sit on" as a whole?

Comment: @user48070 Yup.